# Run another python file's function in discord bot

Tags: python, twitter, discord.py

I have the following discord bot code in Python:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import TwitterSentiments as TS

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$",help_command=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

@client.command(name="stock")
async def stock_sentiment(ctx):

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
    await ctx.send('Enter ticker symbol: ')
    msg = client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    ticker = str(msg).upper()
    TS.find_tweets(ticker)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run("SECRET")
```

And I have another file named TwitterSentiments.py:

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob

#Consumer keys
consumer_key = 'SECRET'
consumer_secret = 'SECRET'

#Access tokens
access_token = 'SECRET'
access_token_secret = 'SECRET'

#Authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#Main function to get tweets
def find_tweets(ticker_symbol):
    #Search for tweets with ticker symbol
    public_tweets = api.search(ticker_symbol)
    #Empy list for average of all sentiments
    sentiment_average_list = []

    for tweet in public_tweets:
        analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
        sentiment_average_list.append(analysis.sentiment.polarity)

    return sentiment_average_list
```

How do I run the find_tweets function inside of the stock_sentiment function in my discord bot code? When I run the code, the bot doesn't even log in, however it works fine if I exclude `import TwitterSentiments as TS`

Comment: Well, that's the way you do it.  You'll have to add some debug prints to figure out where it's getting stuck.  Does TwitterSentiments.py run if you start it by itself?

Comment: @TimRoberts TwitterSentiments.py does run by itself.